# Why does .*(?!Integration)Test match FooIntegrationTest?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex to run all unit tests but not run integration tests.  Unit tests are named `FooTest`, integration tests are named `BarIntegrationTest`, with "Foo" and "Bar" being variables.  [I found this article on how to do it and I have solved my problem](http://jimbarritt.com/non-random/2010/05/28/make-fireworks-intellij-plugin-ignore-integration-tests/).  But, its solution is to use this regex:

```
(.(?!Integration))*Test
```

I don't understand why this regex doesn't suffice:

```
.*(?!Integration)Test
```

When I tried that second regex, my Integration tests were still run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a negative look *ahead*, but you want a negative look *behind*:

```
.*(?<!Integration)Test
```

Your regex is asserting that "Test" is not "Integration", which of course is always true.

Comment: Awesome.  And now I understand the difference between negative look ahead/behind enough to say that the answer from that article is a little awkward.  I think your solution is more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(?!Integration)Test
```

This involves `.*` eating up the whole string and then backtracking to match `Test`.For exmaple if test string is `Integration test` `.*` eats up the whole string and then applies the looahead which passes as after `Test` there is no `integration`.
Once `.*` backtracks to match `t` from `Test` it again applies lookahead but fails so proceeds and matches Test in similar way applying the lookahead at each step.

[image]

Comment: One little mistake in your answer: The lookahead doesn't look for `Integration` __after__ `Test`, it looks for `Integration` right there at the start of `Test`.

Comment: The use of the greedy quantifier `.*` is irrelevant to the problem here. Your answer doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: Wasn't downvoted by me, but there are too many typos in this answer for me to have confidence in it.

Comment: @Rawing no the lookahead will be tested at the end first then when backtracking occurs it will be tested again .See edit